# Interpretation issues of value and par with optim function in R

Tags: r, optimization, sampling, minimize, quantitative-finance

I have tried to minimize a function with optim in R. The problem is that I am not sure the real interpretation I should give to the output value. As I am trying to estimate a parameter such that my function is 0, then I don't really understand why the value of my function with the parameter it estimates is different from 0. 
Tough When I assume lower bounderis (upper and lower) (they are not the correct one), the value of my function is lower with the paramter it estimates. 
Should I be worried about the value of the function?

It is the first time when I am optimizing a function, I would really appreciate some help!
I provide the code and the output.

```
calcr <- function(time, price, freq) {
input <- data.table(time=time,price=price);
input[order(time),];
out <- input[,.(return=log(price[length(price)]/price[1])),
           by=.(time=as.POSIXct(trunc(unclass(time)/freq)*freq,
                                origin='1970-01-01'))];
print(input)
print(out)
return(out);
}

target.fn <- function(m,data) {
trade.interval <- data[,.(interval=difftime(max(time,na.rm=T),
                                          min(time,na.rm=T),
                                          units = "secs")),
                     by=day(time)][,mean(interval,na.rm=T)];
 r <- calcr(time=data$time,price=data$price,
         freq=unclass(trade.interval)/m);
a <- (mean(r$return^2,na.rm=T))^2;
b <- -3*a+2*(mean(r$return^4,na.rm=T));
q  <- r[,.(qi=m/3*sum(return^4)),by=day(time)][,mean(qi,na.rm=T)];
return(abs(2*m^3*a+m^2*b-2*q));
}

##lower=6,upper=23398
optim(par=60,fn=target.fn,data=aa[,.(time,price=nbbomidstart)],
  method='Brent',lower=6,upper=23300);
```

The output I get is the following:

```
$`par`
[1] 4641.689

$value
[1] 56480.07

$counts
function gradient 
      NA       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Are you trying to optimize a function or are you actually trying to find the zero of the function? These are two different things. The former seeks the value of `x` such that `f(x)` is maximum; the latter seeks `x` such as `f(x) = 0`. What's your goal? In the latter case you should check `?uniroot`.

Comment: I am trying to find the zero of the function. As you are saying f(x)=0. Then in this case, should I use another optimization function?

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was another problem there. The problem was with the data which introduced some noise in my data. Once I fixed that issue, my code actually works pretty well, and the value of the function tends to 0, unless I am using some prices which are weird. That problem was caused by using midquote start prices instead of end prices, which does not introduce so much noise in the function.